# What pattern i should use for general field?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have a class `Field` of which there are two sub-classes `AccountField` and `DecimalField`.

ie

```
class Field{//some properties} 

class DecimalField : Field {...}

class AccountField : Field {...}
```

I then have another class `Data` which has a member property of type `Field`.

But it has problems. If I assign a `DecimalField` variable to the `Field` property within `Data` then I cannot use some properties of `DecimalFields` and also same for `Accountfield`  variables...

What must I do? Which pattern I must use?

I am using C# 4.0 and MS Studio 2010

Comment: Can you supply code as an example? Your question itself is quite confusing.

Comment: Class Field{//some properties}
Class DecimalField:Field
{
  char  decimalpointer;
}

class Data
{
Field myField
}

Field.decimalpointer  is error?

Which pattern should I use?

Comment: That entirely depends on how you use your Data objects. CAn you give examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

Let's say that you have your field class like this

```
public class Field
{
   public string Property1{get;set;}
   public int Property2 {get;set;}
}
```

and the decimal field class like this

```
  public class DecimalField:Field
   {
    public int DecimalFieldProperty {get;set;}
}
```

,and the Accountfield  like this

```
public class AccountField:Field
    {
       public double Balance{get;set;}
}
```

, and suppose you have a method called DoSomething, which expects a parameter of **Field** type like the one below

```
void DoSomething(Field field)
{}
```

Then to get the concrete type passed in, you can do something like

```
    void DoSomething(Field field)
    {
        var decimalField = field as DecimalField;

        //Do something with the decimal field instance
        if(decimalField  !=null)
         {
           Console.WriteLine("Decimal Field Property {0}",decimalField .DecimalFieldProperty );
          return;

        }

        //Cast the field as a account field instance
      var accountField = field as AccountField;
       if(accountField !=null)
       {
         Console.WriteLine("Balance {0}", accountField.Balance );

        return;
      }

      //Do something else with the normal field
    Console.WriteLine("Normal Field");

    }
```

Comment: This answer would be better if you demonstrated how to access the `DecimalFieldProperty` and `Amount` properties within the specific types...

Answer (score 2):

The **general**, or **abstract** approach is to :

- create a common generic class with virtual functions/properties that can be overridden in child classes.
- and on the child class members which are *strictly* realted to the specified type, so can not be generalized, make a `cast`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use properties that are in both the DecimalField and AccountField types, these properties should/could be in the Field type.

If you want to use properties only known to DecimalField, you'll need to cast the Field to DecimalField:

```
Data data = new Data();
data.Field = new DecimalField();
Field field = data.Field;
DecimalField df = data.Field as DecimalField;
if(df != null)
{
    // use df
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism is not really a pattern, but yes, it works correctly the way you described it. If you assign DecimalField to a variable of a type Field you will only be able to use properties of the Field.
If you need properties of DecimalField you'll need to convert it back to DecimalField.

Answer (score 0):

In your Data class, don't declare your fields as Field, but use DecimalField or AccountField as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work:

```
Field field = myData.Fields[0];
Console.Writeline(field.Name); //assuming Name only exists in AccountField
```

but if the field is AccountField, then you can do a *reference conversion* and use the AccountField specific properties:

```
if(myData.Fields[0] is AccountField)
{
    var acctField = (AccountField)myData.Fields[0];
    Console.Writeline(acctField.Name);
}
```